# sqlalchemy multiple filter_by unrolling order

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using a `filter_by` statement in sqlalchemy like this:

```
all_animals = self.session.query(Animals).filter_by(
            food=self.food,
            continent=self.continent,
            planet=self.planet).all()
```

In order to use a multi-column index efficiently I would like to determine the order in which these filters are applied in the resulting SQL. From empirical tests it appears that the above query will result in:

```
SELECT * FROM ANIMALS WHERE planet = ? and continent = ? and food = ?
```

I am trying to find some kind of document that can confirm this order.

I used sqlalchemy this way, because coming from the django ORM it felt natural to do so. I tried to find this syntax in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by), however it appears this is a non-documented feature.

I found it in the source code though:

## orm/query.py line 1511

```
def filter_by(self, **kwargs):
    clauses = [_entity_descriptor(self._joinpoint_zero(), key) == value
               for key, value in kwargs.items()]
    return self.filter(sql.and_(*clauses))
```

It seems they are just unpacked into the `sql.and_` operator. Can anyone confirm that the order of the resulting SQL query is the `kwargs` order in reverse?

Comment: I believe you can do `print(str(query)))` to get the raw query, although it will not show any dialect specifics.

Comment: Thanks, I have turned `echo=True` on, and I can see that for the few sample queries I ran it is the reversed order. I just can't find it in the source/documentation and do not wish to rely on anecdotal evidence.

Comment: Hmmm is it not due to `.items()` [CPython implementation details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) since its doing kwargs.items() to a list?

Comment: I think it's an excellent thought. This can also be connected to python 3.6 where one of the features is that ordering of `kwargs` will be preserved!

Comment: What backend are you using that cares about the order?

Comment: postgresql multicolumn index

Comment: PostgreSQL does not care about the ordering of boolean expressions. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/64e4d/2/0